# Is a bittorrent question relevant to superuser.com?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I put up a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877263/chokes-and-updates-to-bittorrent-specs) which got flagged as being off-topic with it being suggested to edit the question and putting it on superuser.com but before doing that, asking here. Could somebody look at it and tell whether it's on-topic or off-topic to the site.

Also if not, give recommendations where the question might be considered on-topic.

`Image added`
[image]

Comment: Your question on [so] has been deleted and can't be viewed by <10K users.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Specifically 10K+ reputation with SO not SU.

Comment: @Ramhound You don't "need" reputation to see deleted questions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Part of it is on topic, part of it isn't.

Asking the questions of the first few paragraphs should be OK. As for asking which client programs, what release and where they're released, would be off topic as it would be an ever-changing even, and turn into a list based question (which is off topic).

I'd suggest a couple things first:

- Remove acronyms. Spell out what you're saying.
- Focus on one, well thought out question at a time. If others are "related" but asking for other things, you are free to link to the first question you'd be posting.
- Make sure the one specific question is pointed out, and not in the middle of a paragraph. If it makes grammatical sense (rarely does), then you should **BOLD** it to make it stand out (use two asterisks like `**this**`)

Comment: While I have tried to focus and make it a single question, I am at loss as to where I should be bolding it. Anyways, have made it at https://superuser.com/questions/886064/chokes-not-interested-peers-in-bittorrent-why-does-it-happen